# Using clientside_validation project, default validation plugin message not being overridden for states dependent field

Tags: 7, javascript, forms

I am currently using [clientside_validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) with clientside_validation_states to validate conditionally required fields.

The issue I am experiencing is when the conditionally required element is invalid (empty), it is showing the generic "This field is required" (from jQuery.validation defaults) instead of using a message that is typically seen (and shows on all other, non-conditionally required fields) - for example, "First Name field is required".

I am using a custom errorPlacement method, but I'm not sure that it matters:

```
    // custom error placement
    Drupal.clientsideValidation.prototype.replaceLabel = function (error, element)  {
      var label, origLabel;
      var wrapperClass = 'formReplacedLabel';
      var WrapperEl = 'span';
      label = element.siblings('label');
      if (label.find('.form-replaced-label').length === 0) {
        label.wrapInner("<span class='form-replaced-label'></span>");
      }
      label.addClass('labelError');
      label.prepend(error);
    };
```

So, the error being passed (for the states dependent control) to the custom errorPlacement method is just the default `$.validator.messages.required` instead of what is passed for the other controls.  I can't just change `.messages.required` to something that is for this field specifically either, as I have several forms with state dependent fields.

I have attached an animated gif that I think can explain the issue better than I do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug. The hot fix is to add the `$message` argument to the `_clientside_validation_set_equal()` call on clientside_validation_fapi.module. So that it looks like: 
`_clientside_validation_set_equal($name, $title, $params[0], $js_rules, $message);`.

I've started an issue and submitted a patch https://drupal.org/node/2140163